# igraph - Color Edges of Union of two different trees

Tags: r, igraph

Hi I am using igraph to make a union of two trees. In making this union, note that the two trees has common names. I want to color the graph union such that the color of edges are preserved.

```
n<-3
n2<-3
tree<-make_tree(n)
tree2<-make_tree(n2)

tree<-set.vertex.attribute(tree, "name", value=letters[1:n])
tree2<-set.vertex.attribute(tree2, "name", value=sample(letters[1:n2]))
E(tree)$color <- "blue"
E(tree2)$color<-"red"
plot(tree)
plot(tree2)
tree_union<-tree %u% tree2
plot(tree_union)
```

For example, a->b and a->c is still blue (tree) and c->a and c->b is still red (tree2). Obviously, I do not want to manually set the color of each edge. I was thinking something like

```
E(tree_union)[E(tree_union)==E(tree)]$color<-"blue"
```

but, it doesn't work because the equality does not check whether two edges are equal.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The original colors were preserved in color_1 and color_2. So you can easily create a color variable to maintain the edge colors. However, in some cases, one of your edges plots over top of another so that all you see is the arrow head.

```
TU_col = edge_attr(tree_union, "color_1")
E2 = which(is.na(edge_attr(tree_union, "color_1")))
TU_col[E2] = edge_attr(tree_union, "color_2")[E2]
tree_union2 = set_edge_attr(tree_union, "color", value=TU_col)
plot(tree_union2)
```

[image: Tree union with color]